# Node.js request SSL error: SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1

Tags: node.js, ssl, request

I am making a request to a remote server using https and request, and getting a new error after updating node and request:

```
nes.get err: [Error: 140735207432576:error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741:
```

I already have the protocol set to SSLv3, so I'm wondering why it appears to be using tlsv1.

```
https.globalAgent.options.secureProtocol = 'SSLv3_method';
```

I've also tried adding this to request's options:

```
secureProtocol: 'SSLv3_method'
```

This error did not occur with earlier versions of Node.js and request, but now with node v0.10.15 and request 2.26.0, it has surfaced. Any ideas? Thanks!

Update -- narrowed this down to something that changes between request 2.14.0 and 2.16.0. 2.14.0 works and 2.16.0 does not work.

Comment: Does this thread help ? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/5XxHhuia-lw   .

Comment: I met the same problem.  Did you get the answer yet?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are making a secure request to the correct port.

I've received this error when attempting to make a secure request to port 80 instead of port 443.

Comment: Thanks, it's definitely the correct protocol and port though.

Answer (score 0):

I would fire up Wireshark to verify that the bits on the wire are what you think they should be.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not qualified to debug this situation at the bit level :)

Comment: Then you are in luck -- read the SSL protocol spec, then you can qualify yourself. Sorry I don't have anything automatic lined up for you.